# invoking a bean method in jsp page

Tags: java, oop, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I have a class which would create a bean and the bean has few get and set methods(for example setId, and getId, now im including this java file in a jsp page, now my question is how to forward the values returned by the bean to the jsp file ?

Kindly help.

Comment: may be as request parameter,but what have u tried? need more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be something you have in your servlet:

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean(); //This should be your bean
Object o1 = bean.getObject1(); //Please don't use Object, use the correct type
Object o2 = bean.getObject2();

request.setAttribute("name",o1); //name can be anything you want
request.setAttribute("test",o2);
//forward to JSP
```

=======================================

In your jsp you could use EL:

```
<!-- This is the firstObject -->
<p>${name}</p>

<!-- This is the second Object -->
<b>${test}</b>
```

=======================================

Or the older style with use:Bean:

```
<!-- This is the first Object, use the correct type in class -->
<jsp:useBean id="name" scope="request" class="java.lang.Object" />
```

Now you can access the properties of the bean:

```
<jsp:getProperty name="name" property="firstName"/>
```

or:

```
<%= name.getFirstName() %>
```

=======================================

Normally it is very rare that the second part is used. Most people use EL these days. But i just included it, to cover everything

Answer (score 2):

Just put the bean in the scope you need it to be available. For example, if it's the `User` class which needs to be in the session scope:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
```

This way the `user` instance is available by the attribute name `"user"` in EL as follows `${user}`. Then, to access its properties as done by the getter methods, just use the period `.` operator in EL wherein you specify the property name.

```
${user.id} 
${user.firstname}
${user.lastname}
...
```

No need to put all attributes individually in request scope.

#### See also:

- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: +1 for the wiki links.  BTW, how would i navigate to them from the front page ?